# Angular - remove routing with services in lazy loading routing modules

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular2-routing, angular-services

I'm working on an angular 2 projects (angular version 2.2.3) with lazy loaded routings. The problem is now I need to remove some routes dynamically by using services. 
The problem is I'm not sure how to use the services outside of class ( approach 1 ).
If I move the service inside of constructor, I'm not sure how to modify the routes since I only get parent ones, not the lazy loaded ones ( approach 2) 
Something like the commented code below:

```
let crisisCenterRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'crisis-center',
    component: CrisisCenterComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: CrisisListComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];

//approach 1: no constructor to inject serviceXX to
//crisisCenterRoutes = serviceXX.process(crisisCenterRoutes);

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(crisisCenterRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class CrisisCenterRoutingModule {
  constructor(serv: ServiceXX, router: Router) {
    let modifiedRoutes = serv.process(crisisCenterRoutes);  
    let newRoutes = router.config;
    //approach 2: not sure how to combine newRoutes and modifiedRoutes from here since newRoutes don't contain the lazy loaded ones
    newRoutes = ??? //combine the newRoutes and modifiedRoutes
    router.resetconfig(newRoutes);
  }
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks before!

Comment: I'm guessing you need to remove those routes depending on user rights/groups. A better way to solve this would be to use the [CanActivate](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivate-interface.html) interface

Comment: By canActivate you mean using guard? guard works fine, but I need it to be removed in this case since I'm using it for generating menu and other stuff afterward

Comment: You cannot know the lazy loaded routes beforehand, unless you manually specify them somewhere. The data is not yet known, because it has not been loaded yet

Comment: the one that I need to remove is crisisComponentRouter, so in this case I have the routes. basically I will remove them before it got lazy loaded

Comment: Have a similar problem where I am trying to remove a route out of the route array depending on a certain condition that I am getting from a service. I can not use a guard for it because of some project regulations.